# Chai-As-Promised passing test even when its throwing an error

Tags: selenium, typescript, mocha.js, chai-as-promised

```
public clickOnElementWithSelectionMethod(elementKey, selectionMethod, selectionValue) {

let elementToClick = this.getWebElement(elementKey, selectionMethod, selectionValue);

    return assert.eventually.equal(
      elementToClick.click().then(() => {
        return true;
      }, (error: any) => {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }), true, 'Element "' + elementKey + '" click failed'
    );
}
```

I'm passing protractor's Click() API call as the promise, [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click).

Even when im passing a wrong `selectionValue`, it shows as the test is passed, but fails the next test.

[image]

Comment: Please show the *actual Mocha test* in which you are using the code you show in your question.

Comment: You must return the promise of `elementToClick.click()` because the error is thrown when it is rejected